# How do a 'or' operation in sails-dynamodb

Tags: node.js, sails.js, amazon-dynamodb

Can any body explain me how to do an OR condition on sails-dynamodb?

I tried

```
let query = {
        where: {
            or: [
                {
                    title: { contains: 'P' },
                    title: {contains: 'p'}
                },
                {
                    description: { contains: 'P' },
                    description: {contains: 'p'}
                }
            ]
        },
        sort: "1"
    }
```

Thanks